# Does current develops instantaneously as we apply potential difference?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, speed-of-light, voltage, conductors

I had this doubt from the starting since I studied current electricity, that if we apply a potential diff. Across a resistor, does the current flow instantaneously, if it does then the communication will take place by speed faster than $c$. And if it doesn't then what is the delay in the process and on what factors does it depend. And a *function* for it. I looked up for this q. On web, and asked several of my physics professor but none got me a satisfactory solution.

Comment: Not if we assume potential difference changes instantaneously, but in fact even that can't happen - any real change we can do will cause only continuous change of electric potential.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on the physical size of the circuit and the rate at which things change as to whether or not the speed of the electromagnetic waves need to be included in the analysis.

If that is not the case then because the circuit is in the form of a loop it will have inductance, which has the property of opposing change in the current.
If there is a wire loop of diameter $30\,\rm cm$ then the self inductance of the circuit is of the order of $1\,\mu H$.
The characteristic time over which a change happens is called the time constant and is equal to $\dfrac{\rm inductance}{\rm resistance}$, thus if the resistance of the resistor (and the rest of the circuit) is $1\,\rm k\Omega$ then changes in the circuit, eg the final current reaching a steady value after a switch is closed, will take about $10^{-6}/10^3= 10^{-9} \,\rm s$.

This type of inductance is sometimes called [*parasitic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitic_element_(electrical_networks)) inductance and there may also be some parasitic capacitance in the circuit which also slow changes down.

Answer (score 0):

> if we apply a potential diff. Across a resistor, does the current flow instantaneously, if it does then the communication will take place by speed faster than c

You are correct, the currents (and voltages) do not change instantaneously, and it would violate the "light speed" limit if they did.

> if it doesn't then what is the delay in the process and on what factors does it depend. And a function for it.

To answer this question we actually have to evaluate the electric and magnetic fields around the circuit. Analyzing the circuit this way, we treat the voltages and currents in the wires (and resistors, etc.) as being caused by the fields around the circuit rather than vice versa.

To evaluate the fields, we are basically solving Maxwell's equations, using the circuit structure to provide the boundary conditions for the solution. We usually can't do this analytically and we have to search for a numerical solution instead. We can do that with a software tool like Ansys HFSS or CST Microwave studio.

In some very simple cases (for example, a signal on a wire at a fixed height above a ground plane), we can find useful approximate solutions, and use them to analyze more complex circuits by treating other elements of the circuit as if they are lumped (small enough to ignore electromagnetic propagation effects) elements.